# How to use HSL for Haxe in FDT 5.5?

Tags: signals, haxe, fdt

I've become a big fan of AS3Signals (https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals), so I wanted to find something similar in Haxe. HSL (http://code.google.com/p/hxhsl/) seems to be the good answer.

In the introduction (http://code.google.com/p/hxhsl/wiki/PrefaceAndIntroduction), the author explains what to add the HXML to compile.

> Using You will have to tell the compiler that you're using the
>   library. There are a couple of ways to do this.
>
> If you are using a HXML file to compile your project, just add the
>   following line to that file:
>   -lib hsl-1

Since FDT is using an HXML file as well, I did just that, however I get an error in the problems view, yet there is no description.

Is there something that I should do differently?

---

I had tried a couple of these things before, then I tried what you suggested, here is what I found.

I already went through haxelib to install HSL (since that's what the author suggested). I checked what I have installed, here it is:

[image: haxelib in Terminal]

Something peculiar happens in FDT: if I use the path found in the Terminal (`/usr/bin/haxe`), FDT throws an error.

[image: FDT prefs error]

So I have to use `/usr/lib/haxe` for some reason.

[image: FDT prefs]

If I try to simply write the import code in the Haxe class, I get a proper error:

[image: normal error]

However, if I try to add the library in the hxml arguments, I get an error with no explanation:

[image: error no text]

Then I tried the option of add the library source files in the project, but still I get an error:

[image: error with lib]

So I guess my question is: where did I not follow your instructions properly?

Comment: First thing to do, is to use FDT 5.5 and Haxe 2.09. (Both are latest), Do that and then see what is wrong. If you download / update to FDT 5.5 you'll have Haxe 2.09: fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download

Comment: Once I download and install anew FDT 5.5, will I lose all my prefs and customizations I've made to my current install? I had updated my FDT from 5.0 to 5.5 to 5.5.1. It is my current work tool, fiddling with it may render my tool unusable for the work I have to do for my clients, it's something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: If you're using the latest FDT 5.5.X, then you're ok and don't need a fresh install. Just make you're pointing to Haxe 2.09 (I describe this in my answer). Haxe 2.08 is ok but 2.09 is better.

Comment: Unfortunately as you suggested in a previous comment, the update might have not gotten the latest haxe, since using /Applications/FDT 5.app/Contents/FDT5/haxe/haxe-2.09-osx gives mes an error. That's why I was referring to the haxe that NME installed. So far, no matter what haxe I use, I get an error. :'(

Comment: Not sure what else to say. FDT's Haxe support is very simple, it just passes the .HXML file to the Haxe compiler and reports back any errors. If you see an error, it's from the Haxe compiler. I would skip NME and just focus on getting Haxe working.

Comment: How about downloading another FDT standalone, separately and try that?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I just tried to reinstall FDT, it points to haxe version 2.09, but I still get an error with hsl no matter what. I have put my code on github (https://github.com/jansensan/test-haxe-hsl), if it helps you to browse through it, maybe it's obvious, but I'm looking at a tree rather than at the forest...

Comment: A better way to test is not even deal with code. Just use haxelib to download hsl. Then add the '-lib [hsl lib name]' argument. If you don't get an error, Haxe found it. http://haxe.org/doc/haxelib/using_haxelib

Comment: Alright! So it seems that indeed the FDT update did not upgrade haxe from 2.07 to 2.09, so uninstalling the version I had, download the latest and resintall fixed the thing, using the -lib argument.

Sad that this was the case, since now I have to reinstall the other views I had...

In any case, thanks so much for the help! I updated my Github repo with valid code, for both events and hsl signals: https://github.com/jansensan/test-haxe-hsl

Answer (score 2):

### HSL is not accessible to the Haxe compiler.

Usually the error looks like this when  missing source code is referenced:
[image]

### There Are Two Ways To Make It Visible

1. Use haxelib ([link](http://haxe.org/doc/haxelib/using_haxelib))
2. Add the source code directly to the project.

### Use Haxelib

To use Haxelib & FDT, make sure that FDT and your $PATH are pointing to the same Haxe compiler.  Also make sure HSL has been installed (It's not by default). Learn how to do this on the Haxelib link above.

If you're on OSX, you can't navigate to the SDK inside of FDT's package. You can copy & paste it. It will be like this: /Applications/FDT 5.app/Contents/FDT5/haxe/haxe-2.09-osx

[Also see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939596/how-do-i-navigate-update-the-haxe-sdk-inside-of-fdt/)

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Add Source Directly To FDT

This is easy. Just check out the source code from HSL repository. Add the contents of 'hsl-pico source' to your project. Then add it as a source folder.

[image]