# How Do I Navigate / Update The Haxe SDK Inside of FDT?

Tags: sdk, installation, haxe, fdt

On OSX, FDT has the Haxe SDK here:

/Applications/FDT 5.app/Contents/FDT5/haxe/haxe-2.09-osx

Because this is inside of a OSX package, I can't navigate to it. How to I either:

1. Select it in the preferences.
2. Update it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Manually Copy / Paste the path. Here is an example:

`/Applications/FDT 5.app/Contents/FDT5/haxe/haxe-2.09-osx`

2. Update / replace the SDK via the find by going to 'Show Package Contents'

[image]

[image]