# Haxe SDK missing in FDT on OSX

Tags: haxe, fdt

I have downloaded the latest (free) FDT and when I try to create new Haxe project I am asked to specify the Haxe SDK installation path but this is nowhere to find.

[image]

It is not in the FDT5 content folder as [this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939596/how-do-i-navigate-update-the-haxe-sdk-inside-of-fdt), there is simply no HAXE folder inside FDT.

I am not sure if the SDK is FDT specific so I have also installed the [OSX Haxe installer](http://haxe.org/download) but again there is no path or anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that haxe was installed under usr/ folder that is by default hidden on Mac and can not be located by browsing the disk and command line has zero discoverability and unnecessary learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just point it to the place where you installed haxe? (And this place is *not* in FDT plugins folder, since haxe isn't FDT plugin.)

Comment: the problem was that haxe was installed under usr/ folder that is by default hidden on Mac and can not be located by browsing the disk and command line has zero discoverability and unnecessary learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX you should probably simply use **/usr/lib/haxe** in your *Haxe SDK path* field

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can `ln -s /usr/local local` while in your home directory.  Then you can navigate to your home (in /Users/yourname) and choose local.  From there choose bin and it can find the 'haxe' command.